# Have there been explanations offered for why Christianity is so food centric?

Tags: christian-living, comparative-christianity, diet, covenants

I know this question is quite odd - but I would like to know of possible explanations for why the old and new covenants are so centered around food? The last supper, the bread of the presence, the manna and quail, etc. it seems like it bears a lot of significance and I want to know if there have been any reasons offered as why.

Comment: Other religions have extensive rules about food whereas Christianity does not. And all but one of the things you mention are Jewish. I don't see Christianity as food-centric.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the notions of sacrifice and also receiving nourishment from God, especially receiving nourishment during the 40 years in the desert, which is a Christian Type.

Comment: One of the central themes of the Bible is "We get our life from God." So the act of taking in food and the act of breathing, which are both essential for physical life, become valuable metaphors.

Comment: I like the question at hand, but feel it is in need of better explanations in order to clarify your thoughts.

Comment: The New Testament ... "Man cannot live on bread alone" (Matthew 4:4; citing Debt 8:3), "I am the bread of life" (John 6:35), "Jesus declared all foods clean" (Mark 7:19) and the entire Book of Hebrews. The New Testament definitely points to God rather than food. Rephrase the question towards Roman Catholicism and centrality of trans-subtantiation??

Comment: Does the question apply strictly to *eating* food, or does it include *production* and *preparation*? For instance, most of God's holy days are based on agriculture, and much prophecy is about sowing and reaping, separating the sheep from the goats, slaughtering animals, etc. ¶ As it stands now, this question is either too big or too small.

Comment: I’m actually going to agree this question is not specific enough. Please vote to close.

Comment: Perhaps the question should ask why Jesus of Nazareth mentioned food (particularly bread) and even likened Himself to bread (saying 'I am the bread of life). After all, 'Christianity' is that which follows Christ.

Comment: *"Questions that can be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed. They must be edited to ask for one perspective, or to explicitly ask for an overview of all Christian positions.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have there been explanations offered for why Christianity is so food centric?**

Food is important to human life!

Man by his very nature needs food and drink (water) in order to sustain himself in life. Without nourishment a person would die. From the very beginning man has been offering food stuffs to the Lord as a form of prayer either in thanksgiving or in supplication.

Exodus shows us how God, through Moses, imposed the Passover onto the Jewish people. It is explicitly asked that if the meal is too big for a family to consume then they are to invite another to join them with the Passover meal. This brings me to an important point.

Man is a social being and needs the companionship of other individuals in order to maintain a health lifestyle. God knows this all too well when the Passover was instituted. Read the Jewish Ritual of how the Passover meal is done and you will understand.

In the New Testament, Our Lord instituted the Eucharist as the means of union of man with God. Thus man’s nutrition became both natural and Divine for those those who believe that the Eucharist is the body and blood of Jesus Christ. Some Christians believe this is only symbolic which for the sake of this post is fine.

Today many churches gather round the table of the Lord to celebrate the Eucharist in a group setting of believers. Man is a social being striving towards union with God with the help of God and others for support.

We see Abraham offering bread to his three mysterious visitors. Food is ever so important in the life a of mankind.

Partaking a meal (food) together symbolizes unity and friendship in this life, especially in the realm of beliefs, even if abuses crept in.

This brings me to another point that is brought up in the New Testament. It concerns the **agape feast** which was a communal meal shared amongst the Early Church Christians. Abuses in it lead to severe criticism by some, even though the basic idea for Christians to share a common meal has some profound religious meaning and tradition.

> An agape feast or lovefeast (also spelled love feast or love-feast, sometimes capitalized) is a communal meal shared among Christians. The name comes from agape, a Greek term for 'love' in its broadest sense.
>
> The lovefeast originated in the early Church and was a time of fellowship for believers. The Eucharist was often a part of the lovefeast, although at some point (probably between the latter part of the 1st century AD and 250 AD), the two became separate. Thus, in modern times the Lovefeast refers to a Christian ritual meal distinct from the Eucharist or Lord's Supper. The lovefeast seeks to strengthen the bonds and the spirit of harmony, goodwill, and congeniality, as well as to forgive past disputes and instead love one another.
>
> The practice of the lovefeast is mentioned in Jude 1:12 of the Christian Bible and was a "common meal of the early church".[9] References to communal meals are discerned in 1 Corinthians 11:17–34, in Saint Ignatius of Antioch's Letter to the Smyrnaeans, where the term agape is used, and in a letter from Pliny the Younger to Trajan, (ca. 111 A.D.) in which he reported that the Christians, after having met "on a stated day" in the early morning to "address a form of prayer to Christ, as to a divinity", later in the day would "reassemble, to eat in common a harmless meal". Similar communal meals are attested also in the Egyptian Church Order often identified as the Apostolic Tradition attributed to Hippolytus of Rome, who does not use the term agape, and in works of Tertullian, who does. The connection between such substantial meals and the Eucharist had virtually ceased by the time of Cyprian (died 258), when the Eucharist was celebrated with fasting in the morning and the agape in the evening. The Synod of Gangra in 340 makes mention of lovefeasts in relation to a heretic who had barred his followers from attending them.
>
> Though still mentioned in the Quinisext Council of 692, the agape fell into disuse soon after, except among the churches in Ethiopia and India. At the end of the 18th century the Carmelite friar Paolino da San Bartolomeo reported that the ancient **Saint Thomas Christians of India still celebrated the lovefeast, using their typical dish called appam. In addition, Radical Pietist groups originating in the eighteenth-century, such as the Schwarzenau Brethren and the Moravian Church, celebrate the lovefeast. Methodist churches also continue the practice**. - [Agape feast](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agape_feast)

The idea that Christianity is somewhat food centric is completely normal as we share our life sustaining foods together in unity, such as in the family unit! This is in a sense the most basic level of things Christians can be gathered together to enjoy!

There is one more point I would like to mention before ending. Some cultural and historical events have put into place some local traditions that amplify this food centric desire amongst Christians in one way or another. Allow me to give a small example, as many can be found:

> St. Lucy is the patron saint of the city of Syracuse (Sicily). On 13 December a silver statue of St. Lucy containing her relics is paraded through the streets before returning to the Cathedral of Syracuse. Sicilians recall a [legend](https://www.sicilianpost.it/en/a-food-of-miracles-saint-lucias-cuccia/) that holds that a famine ended on her feast day when ships loaded with grain entered the harbor. Here, it is traditional to eat whole grains instead of bread on 13 December. This usually takes the form of [***cuccìa***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucc%C3%ACa). a dish of boiled wheat berries often mixed with ricotta and honey, or sometimes served as a savory soup with beans. - [St. Lucy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Lucy)

The following may be of interest to some:

- [List of foods with religious symbolism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_foods_with_religious_symbolism)
- [Catholic Recipes for the Liturgical Year](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/recipes/)

Answer (score 0):

The temples of Hinduism are known for offering of fruit and food items to the deity and distributing them to the faithful once the worship is over. Each temple has a unique way of preparing such food items. For instance, the sweet made of flour and dryfruits in the temple of Tirupati, India has gained a GI Tag ! As for followers of Sikh religion, their feasts are never complete without distribution of free food on the nearest street, to anyone passing by . Muslims share the meat of the chosen  goat  on Bakr-id on which the sacrifice made by Father Abraham is commemorated. That said, Christians share little or no food when they assemble for prayer. Of course, with the advent of packed food, Church groups are now serving lunch or supper to the faithful on special days, mostly to cultivate a sense of brotherhood. (But, never ever think of having your food inside the Church ! )Such sharing of brotherhood via food differs from place to place and culture to culture. So, it is rather the absence of sharing of physical food in Christian community life that calls for explanation , and not the excess of it !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'food centric' but one thing about believers in Jesus Christ is the desire to spend time together, and when you spend time together with others there is a great comradery about food. Pot lucks, banquets, spur of the moment let's grab a bite, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.